# Git authorization on ubuntu differ from win or osx

Tags: git, ubuntu-20.04

I've been using git both on my desktop (osx) and laptop (win10) machines for quite a long time.
All I usually had to do for setting up were set up my global git config username/email, then git clone my repository to local folder, authorize it ONCE and continue pull and push without having to use my credential every single time I wanted to push/pull.

Recently I set up an another computer running Ubuntu 20'04
I did all exactly the same steps for setting up the git but nevertheless it at first: refused authorize me by email/username/password and forced me issuing  an auth token and for second: moreover, now it keeps asking auth information username/password/token every time I use remote github communication git push git pull git fetch etc...

There's a lot of answers around here and there, most state that I have to use either SSH communication or use "credential helper" to have my auth info stored in the system, but actually I'm not very keen to use any of these, providing I didn't use it on my other machines and all was OK.

So now I can't realize and really wonder about why on both other my OS ( osx sierra or win 10) I can store the credentials and don't have to type it every time but on Ubuntu 20 it can't be stored in system and how I can override this.

BTW I noticed the difference when I for the first time was authorized git in bash/command prompt on osx or windows I remember it opened the browser window and use it for authorization, but it doesn't happen on any my Ubuntu authorization trying.

Please, is there any workaround for having my ubuntu git workflow similar I have on win or osx?

Comment: `providing I didn't use it on my other machines` you actually use either of those but mac and win actually "hide" it by setting it up by themselves. For password auth, they use the system keystore which is [the method I would recommend for ubuntu](https://polodev.github.io/learning/bits/how-to-store-git-credential-in-ubuntu-linux-using-libsecret/)

Comment: Thanks, will try it.

Comment: Done ! Excellent! Setting up easily and working like a charm.